# Identification of this symbol from cable design

Tags: power-electronics, schematics, cables, symbol

What is the line segment symbol that's shown to the right of the circular dashed symbol?  I can't seem to find the symbol in any online reference.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Twisted pair.  You have two conductors in a wire, which are wrapped in a twisted pair.

From [Electrical & Electronic Symbols](https://www.electrical-symbols.com/electric-electronic-symbols/lines-wires-conductors-symbols.htm)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Possibly just a (crudely drafted) indication that the cable is not drawn to scale and there is a lot of length not shown. Similar to [this](https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/inventor-forum/electrical-cable-schematic-assembly-drawings-in-inventor/td-p/8916522?lightbox-message-images-8916522=658707i2D00AD1A2BC3BE24):

[image]

Or [this](https://www.compatiblecable.com/inse/environmental/):

[image]